# Problema al cambiar los nombres de las interfaces de red en Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, interface, networking

Estoy experimentando dificultades al intentar cambiar los nombres de las interfaces de red en Debian 11. He seguido los pasos habituales modificando el archivo **/etc/network/interfaces** y reiniciando el servicio de networking, pero los nombres antiguos aún aparecen en **/sys/class/net**, lo miso al colocar el comando **ip address show**. Aquí está la configuración anterior en /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# Archivo /etc/network/interfaces

# Interfaz enp0s3
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.244

# Interfaz enp0s8
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Así está ahora:

```
# Archivo /etc/network/interfaces

# Interfaz enp0s4
auto enp0s4
iface enp0s4 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.244

# Interfaz enp0s9
auto enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet dhcp
```

He reiniciado el servicio de networking utilizando el comando systemctl restar**t networking.service**, pero los cambios no se reflejan en las interfaces de red. También he verificado que no haya otros archivos de configuración en **/etc/network/interfaces.d/** que pudieran interferir. ¿Qué más puedo hacer para asegurarme de que los cambios de nombres de las interfaces se apliquen correctamente en Debian 11?

¡Agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que puedan brindar!

Comment: Cual es la salida de `ip link show`?

Answer (score 0):

En Debian 11 (Bullseye), el archivo /etc/network/interfaces ya no se utiliza para la configuración de las interfaces de red. En su lugar, se utiliza el servicio systemd-networkd para administrar las interfaces.

tenes que cambiar los nombres de red en Debian 11

abri el archivo de configuracion'system-networkd' para '/etc/systemd/network/' y podes usar por ejemplo el siguiente comando

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
```

en ese archivo agrega las lineas para asignar nuevos nombres a las inter...

```
[Match]
```

OriginalName=enp0s3

[Link]
Name=enp0s4

tenes que guardarlo y reinicia
Acordate de ejecutar

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola. No existe dicho archivo

Comment: Hay algún sitio donde pueda ver que el archivo `/etc/network/interfaces` ya no se use? Esto apunta a lo contrario: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#A3_ways_to_configure_the_network